# Installing FreeBSD from USB-Stick boots but later can't find the USB-Stick

Tags: freebsd, usb, system-installation, live-usb

When trying to install FreeBSD 8.2 from USB memory stick the kernel boots from the USB-Stick and the installer menus work and let me partition and everything.

However when it comes to actually installing from the USB-Stick it is not found.

Checking with the emergency shell showed that there are no `/dev/da*` entries visible.

This happened with hardware ASUS P8 H67-M Pro, Intel i7-2600 with EFI BIOS.

Answer (score 5):

I resolved the problem myself:

On a thread about live usb boot [I found the hint](http://forums.freebsd.org/showpost.php?p=118446&postcount=8) that helped solving this:

The USB-stick written with the downloaded original image with `dd` is mounted.
Do this on any version of any *BSD system (need BSD because it needs UFS filesystem mount capability)  Mac OSX would also do BTW.

```
# mount /dev/da0a /mnt
```

Then the following line is appended to the file `/mnt/boot/loader.conf` on the USB-Stick:

```
kern.cam.boot_delay=10000
```

This can be done with an editor or simply on the shell like:

```
# echo "kern.cam.boot_delay=10000" >> /mnt/boot/loader.conf
```

Then unmount the USB-Stick

```
umount /mnt
```

And use it for installation. After this installation worked without problems.

I submitted a [bug report](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/query-pr.cgi?pr=160192), check it for further info.